# How to arrayformula the unique values of 2 arrays of values from 2 tables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Screenshot of Sample Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUc5Z.png)

Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19fSLDDp7k8JIgBsi0YCqJbz-Ue-pLruGv-Sjc3Eo_l0/edit?usp=sharing

There are 2 tables both having Color field which is an array of values separated by ";"

I2:I is a filtered list by a formula as shown in H2.
Now, I want to have an ARRAYFORMULA function in J2 to output the combined array of colors without duplicate.
The sample output is shown in J2:J3.

I can join the array but do not know how to eliminate duplicated values

```
ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(I2:I,A:B,2,FALSE)&";"&VLOOKUP(I2:I,E:F,2,FALSE)
```

I have two ideas but I do not know how to work it out

- use of UNIQUE, SPLIT, TRANSPOSE, TEXTJOIN
- use of REGEXREPLACE

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on? Also, would you be open to using Apps Script [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Comment: @Iamblichus I have added the url. I want to use only formula in this case.
I can solve it with Google Apps Script myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `I2` to get names and colors w/o duplicates at once:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  REGEXREPLACE(
    SPLIT(
      TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
        QUERY(
          UNIQUE(
            SPLIT(
              FLATTEN(
                FILTER(
                  A2:A & "♦♥" & SPLIT(B2:B & IFNA(";" & VLOOKUP(A2:A, E:F, 2,)), ";"),
                  C2:C = True
                )
              ),
              "♥"
            ) & ";"
          ),
          "SELECT MAX(Col2)
           WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY Col2
           PIVOT Col1",
        ),,
        10^7
      )),
      "♦"
    ),
    "^(?:;\s*)+|(?:;\s*)+$|(;)\s*(?:;\s*)*",
    "$1"
  )
)
```

[image]

You can decompose it (just remove one function after another from top to bottom) to figure out how it works.

Comment: Thank you it works!
Now I want to have an advanced application.
Please refer to Sheet 2 and you would find that there are:
(i) an Age column (M) between Name (L) and Color (N)
(ii) a Fruit column (O) after Color (N)

I want to use `FILTER` in L2 outputing both columns L and M that
the formula in N2 no longer needs to ouput the Name column.

I have tried to modify your formula to output Fruit (O) myself and use `QUERY` to eliminate the Name column in the output
but I wonder if there is better approach to do this.

Comment: For instance,
(i) `FILTER` is used thrice in K2, N2 and O2
(ii) the formulas in N2 and O2 are similar
Can we group the formulas in N2 and O2, i.e. outputting N and O by only one formula in N2?

Comment: @idfurw you could just use `VLOOKUP` on the resulting range.

Comment: Okay, I would use `VLOOKUP` and output N and O respectively. Thank you!

Comment: I think `UNIQUE` is not needed because it seems unique value is already provided by `SELECT MAX(Col2)`. What do you think?

Comment: @idfurw That is correct. But I believe that this `UNIQUE` helps `QUERY` do less work though.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I would then leave `UNIQUE` there.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=JOIN(";",UNIQUE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",FILTER($B$2:$B$4,$A$2:$A$4=B7),FILTER($E$2:$E$4,$D$2:$D$4=B7)),";"),TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: I want an arrayformula function in C7 which would output values in C7:C

Comment: For these type of `Join()/Textjoin()` it will be very difficult to implement array formula.

Comment: Can we delete the duplicate values in the joined array with regexreplace?
ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(VLOOKUP(B7:B,A2:B4,2,FALSE)&";"&VLOOKUP(B7:B,D2:E4,2,FALSE),"...","..."))