# Concatenate columns while avoiding blanks and duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

Trying to combine range `E4:I` into `J4:J` with the Array Formula of:

```
=ArrayFormula( regexreplace( regexreplace( transpose( trim( query( transpose( regexreplace( trim( E4:I ) , " " , "~" ) ) ,, 9^99 ) ) ) , " " , ", " ) , "~" , " " ) )
```

This formula works well but I want to exclude duplicates in each row.

Here is a link to the sheet. [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Idt6SWYQ9yjceJGNF0LqIsmIEgP4-YxnD-cSfqChul0/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be in `arrayformula`? This is possible without it, would that be fine?

Comment: It needs to output in the form of an array so that I won't have to drag down formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this modified formula from a similar post:

```
=INDEX(
  REGEXREPLACE(SORT(
    SPLIT(
      TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
        QUERY(
          UNIQUE(
            SPLIT(
              FLATTEN(
                ROW(E2:I11) & "♦♥" & E2:I11
              ), "♥"
            ) & ", "
          ),
          "SELECT MAX(Col2)
           WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY Col2
           PIVOT Col1",
        ),,99
      )),"♦"
    ), 1, TRUE),
    "^(?:,\s*)+|(?:,\s*)+$|(,\s)\s*(?:,\s*)*",
    "$1"
  ),,2)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Output is automatically sorted alphabetically
- You can change `E2:I11` to `E2:I` but it will be slower than limiting your range. If you have a column that can identify until what row is populated, add an `IF` statement and limit your formula to only process those rows.

#### Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67837006/17842569